# Displaying a bitmap as a background

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an image that I want to use as a background but I first need to scale it down to prevent `OutOfMemoryExceptions`

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.home_bkgrnd, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    String imageType = options.outMimeType;
    int sampleSize =1;

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
    if(imageWidth > imageHeight){
        sampleSize = Math.round((float)imageHeight/(float)height);
    }else{
        sampleSize = Math.round((float)imageWidth/(float)width);
    }
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.home_bkgrnd, options);


rl.setBackgroundDrawable(bm);
```

But how do I set the background of my layout to that scaled bitmap since it does not take a bitmap as an argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make bitmap drawable and set it as background.

```
   rl.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bm));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947603/setbackground-vs-setbackgrounddrawable-android