# How to programmatically set EditText background to default in Holo theme Api 11-17 Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

Since I was using

```
EditText et=new EditText(this);
locationEditText.setBackgroundDrawable(et.getBackground());
```

but `setBackgroundDrawable(Drwable)` is deprecated in Api 16 as can't use `setBackground(Drwable)` since it was added in api 16 and I'm using earlier versions than that

So the only two functions left to me

are: `setBackgroundColor(int color)`  and `setBackgroundResource(int resid)`

So how to set it to the default `EditText` in Holo Light Theme?

Answer (score 1):

Use `setBackground(Drawable drawable)` that do the same job of setBackgroundDrawable(Drwable).

edit: thx to Warpzit for this code [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947603/setbackground-vs-setbackgrounddrawable-android):

```
EditText et=new EditText(this);

int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    setBackgroundDrawable(et.getBackground());
} else {
    setBackground(et.getBackground());
}
```

You can find more info [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729675/difference-between-setbackgrounddrawable-and-setbackground)

Comment: Can't this function isn't exist before Api 16 and my range of Apis is from 11-17

Comment: Still the issue of how to set the background of the EditText in latest versions 16+ Apis to Holo Default EditText Theme

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't understand: _Still the issue of how to set the background of the EditText in latest versions 16+ Apis to Holo Default EditText Theme_. My code should work with just a warning advice.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
<EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.EditText"/>
```

Comment: Need it in Code not XML... Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to create a template layout xml file for edittext with the style you need assigned and inflate it when you need it in code.
in XML

Use this in code:

> EditText et = (EditText
>   )getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edtemplate, null);

refereed more at
[android set style in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142067/android-set-style-in-code)