# How to display image in videoview for version below 4.1?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am able to display the thumbnail for videoview from video by using following code,

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever(); 
retriever.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
Bitmap bmp = retriever.getFrameAtTime(2 * 1000000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
mVideoView.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
```

But this `mVideoView.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);` method is available from version 4.1.
How to do it for OS version below 4.1?

Comment: Actually i'd tried your above code to get all frames from video file but i get only the first frames repeatedly.my duration of video is 127040(2:07sec) divided the video to 32 frames can view all 32 images but all were same images i'd tried a lot to fix it with getFrameAtTime(potions) but no use at all exactly i don't knoe where it goes wrong so can you help me by your full source code should i include any thing in AndroidManifest

Answer (score 2):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947603/setbackground-vs-setbackgrounddrawable-android) question:

```
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    mVideoView.setBackgroundDrawable();
} else {
    mVideoView.setBackground();
}
```