# How to setBackgroundResource to a new - seft created drawable?

Tags: android, bitmap

In my app, I created a new bitmap by crop or resize an available image in res/drawable folder, and I convert that bitmap to drawable. I know I can use `setBackgroundDrawable` for that drawable but it requires API 16, that's somehow to high for some devices. 
So how can I get intId of that drawble to use `setBackgroundResource` function?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11947755/2668136) might help you.

Comment: Thank Fllo, you saved my day :-) 
By the way, to use `setbackgroundDrawable` I need to add suppress lint, does it affect my app further and why google need to do that?

Comment: It's not an error, just a warning. It causes by the SDK and Java which say for lower api to not read this method to avoid possible exception. Your app can run without it. And be carefull on *what lines* are under the suppression. Don't suppress all your method because it will never read by any lower apis. I think you can put this on local methods. HTH

Answer (score 1):

`setBackgroundDrawable` is available from API 1

`setBackground` is available from API 16