# Drawable in TextView does not show correctl in adding TextView to LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

i want to add some TextView to a Vertical LinearLayout programmatically.
but there is a strange problem:
when i set a Drawable to these TextViews(using setBackgroundDrawable() method) and add them to LinearLayout programmatically the TextView's Drawable does not show correctly.

this only happen when i have more than one TextView, if there is one the Background Drawable show correctly.

also this only happen when i add TextView programmatically, in the case that i add some TextView in XML Drawable is fine.

My codes:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
linearLinear = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ll);
Drawable mDrawable =getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.textview_drawable);


TextView mTextView;
for(int i =0;i<textViewCount;i++)
{
mTextView = new TextView(context);
mTextView.setText(mText.get(i));
mTextView .setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);
linearLinear.addView(mTextView);
}
```

XML Drawable:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle"
    >
    <solid android:color="#ffddf978" />
    <corners
        android:radius="9dp"
        />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#D7D7D7" />

</shape>
```

for some reason the first TextView's Drawable is not correct but the second is fine.
i take some image from my device screen:

http://i61.tinypic.com/1zd5cu9.png

http://i58.tinypic.com/2nby79e.png

please help me!

sorry for bad English.

Comment: You should post `/res/drawable/textview_drawable.xml`, too.

Comment: i did, is this a bug? or i am doing something WRONG

Comment: `mTextView .setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);` is this a **typo**? remove the space.

Comment: Try to use 9 patch image instead of shape.

Comment: Also have a look to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947603/setbackground-vs-setbackgrounddrawable-android

Comment: try with setBackgroundResource instead of setBackgroundDrawable..

Comment: i do not think this is the problem, i have managed once to show Drawable correctly programmatically, but i do not remember how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i managed to **solve** this problem!

*the problem was* **using a Drawable Instance for multiple TextView with different size.**

this explain why using a single TextView looks fine but multiple not, size are different and the Drawable object's size change for the last TextView is added.

now i used the Drawable in TextView's constructor and it worked!.

if you know betterway please tell me.
thank you.