# Random change of background images in android

Tags: android, random, background

I have an app where there is one constant background image. I want to change this background image randomly on click. How do I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing background image on button click android app development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29735869/changing-background-image-on-button-click-android-app-development)

Answer (score 0):

```
int images[] = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image2};
view.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources.getDrawable(image[new Random().nextInt(images.length())]));
```

Create an array of your drawable
set the background of the view using the drawable on the images array so you need a random index.