# How to use setBackgroundDrawable

Tags: android, imageview

I'm working with image view in android for devices from API 12 to 22. As we know, there are 2 methods for calling `setBackground` differ, whether we use API 16+ or a lower API. 
I do it as most tutorials and other Stack Overflow questions guided, but I still get black color instead of image in the image view. What else should I do to make it work?

```
Bitmap bitmap;
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

bitmap = BitmapDecoder.decodeBitmapFromResource(context.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.sample_photo, 200, 500);

    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        setBackgroundV16Minus(holder.locationImage, bitmap);
    } else {
        setBackgroundV16Plus(holder.locationImage,bitmap);
    }
```

update:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
private void setBackgroundV16Plus(View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
    view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),bitmap));
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void setBackgroundV16Minus(View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
}
```

Comment: you should use `setImageBitmap` / `setImageDrawable`

Comment: Please explain what is not working. Do you get an error or something?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947603/setbackground-vs-setbackgrounddrawable-android

Answer (score 1):

The `setBackgroundDrawable()` method of the Class in is now deprecated in android ***SDK API level 16***

Try this logic

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
  .setBackground(...);
else
  .setBackgroundDrawable(...);
```

Comment: I updated the code, I'm doing the same as you suggest but again not working.