# Android Studio Changing Background theme of activities using 1 button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

Hi guys as i make my quiz application for my thesis i think of adding a shop to buy different THEMES.first i need to know how to set a background using a button?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch(v.getId())

case R.id.btTheme:
                 //no idea :D


            break;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947603/setbackground-vs-setbackgrounddrawable-android

Comment: add xml file, screenshot, in one word: more details

Comment: i just wanna know how to add a background using a button like the background of the activity :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Tj Estrella Manzano
RelativeLayout rel;

in button1.setOnClickListener
write this
rel=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rel);

rel.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

This is the code to change the background color.

if you want to change the background image 
then you have to create a final  Drawable

Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.a); // a is the name of image           stored in  Drawable folder

and then rel.setBackground(drawable);

Comment: ahhh got it thanks :D

Comment: hi is there a way to change the background of other activities too?..

Comment: like for example this button is in main activity and i wanted to change the other activitie's background using only this button is there like a way?

Comment: yes you can just store the value or pass it to other activity..